# The differential of the sum $\sum x_i^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation

I have the following equation which is from a famous paper in economics:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \, dx_i=\frac{1}{2} d\Big[\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2\Big]=XH \, dX+\frac{1}{2}d\big[X^2H\big]
$$
Can you tell me how to get to the second and the third equality sign.

We have that

$$ 
\sum_i^n x_i=X  
$$

and

$$
\sum_i^n \Big(\frac{x_i}{X} \Big)^2=H
$$

I think the "d" $dx_i$ is the same as in a derivative.

Answer (score 3):

The $\rm d$ operator is the [derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative), in a sense. The product (Leibniz) rule applies. And $\rm d$ is additive. Also, chain rule holds. So ${\rm d}(x_i^2) = 2 x_i {\rm d}x_i$. This indeed gives $$\frac{1}{2}{\rm d}\left(\sum x_i^2\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sum d(x_i^2) = \frac{1}{2} \sum 2x_i {\rm d}x_i = \sum x_i {\rm d}x_i,$$ as we wanted.

For the second part, are you sure that $H$ and $X$ are as stated? Look: $$H = \sum \left(\frac{x_i}{X}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{X^2}\sum x_i^2 \implies X^2H = \sum x_i^2 \implies {\rm d}(X^2H) = 2\sum x_i{\rm d}x_i.$$
With that factor $1/2$, we already have that term in the first equality. The $XH{\rm d}X$ parcel is left over.

Comment: It's possible that it was $XHdX + \frac{1}{2}X^2 dH$, which is equal (this is just the product rule on the term $\frac{1}{2} d(X^2H)$).